# How to set autofocus on button inside modal everytime modal pops up?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, button, autofocus

I am using Vue.js 2 to show Bootstrap modal. Below is an example.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" autofocus class="btn btn-primary">Always focus</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that when modal pops up, user should be enable to press the `Enter` key to click on the `Always focus` button without using mouse. And when user press the `left` or `right` arrow button, that the focus switch from `Always focus` button to the `Close` button and vice versa.

With `autofocus` attribute, it works well but only if modal pops up for the every first time. For second time the modal pops up, the `Always focus` button loses focus.

How can I make the `Always focus` button always have focus everytime modal pops up? Or How can I realize the idea using whatever CSS-solution, JavaScript-solution or Vue-solution?

Note that I am using Vue.js 2. Any Vue.js solution is also welcome, but not jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using Vue's `$refs` object. ([see docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)) Essentially, you give the button a `ref` attribute, then you can always access that element in your Vue code by calling `this.$refs.<whatever name you gave it>`:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button ref="always_focus" type="button" autofocus class="btn btn-primary">Always focus</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, add or modify your `show` event handler for the modal:

```
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    onModalShow() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.always_focus.focus();
      });
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

The use of Vue's `$nextTick()` ([docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick)) function here is also important. You have to wait for the button to become visible in order to focus it. By adding the focus code to a `$nextTick()` callback, you can be sure that the DOM has finished updating from the previous change to your data model (eg. the change that shows the modal).

> **NOTE:** the above is just an example, since I don't know exactly what your modal code looks like.

Comment: Using `ref` attribute was a good one, but `$nextTrick()` does not work for me. `this.$refs.always_focus` results `undefined` because modal needs to be rendered first. So the trick was to use `setTimeout()` instead of `$nextTrick()`.

Comment: @OConnor FYI, the function name is $nextTick not $nextT*r*ick

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 'mounted' function to always focus the button when the modal is opened:

```
mounted: function() {
  document.getElementById("focus-button").focus();
}
```

Or you may be able to listen for a keypress and check if it's the enter key and programmatically click the button.

```
onKeyPress: function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    document.getElementById("focus-button").click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `document.getElementById("focus-button").focus()` is another good way. But because modal needs to be rendered first, using `document.getElementById("focus-button").focus()` inside `mounted` does not help. But `document.getElementById("focus-button").focus()` does set focus on the element if you use it inside `setTimeout()`.

Comment: The mounted portion of the vue life-cycle ensures the dom is rendered first. It does not guarantee child elements to be mounted though, so you could use the $nextTick() function in that case. See docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: FWIW, the `mounted` approach works for me inside a simple modal dialog component.